# Что легче - C++ или Java?

Tags: java, c++

Изучаю Java по книге Java 7 - the complete reference. Там часто встречаю микро-сравнения с C++. Из них легко понять одно - Java и C++ похожи (способы исполнения и компиляции данных языков не в счёт), но различия есть. Однако я задался вопросом. **А что сложнее?** Тех микро-сравнений не хватает, чтобы понять это, поэтому бегу на Хэшкод **:)**

p.s. При объяснении учитывайте, что увы C++ я не знаю вообще, а в Java -е нахожусь в состоянии между новичком и среднечком. Так-что если вы будете писать о какой-то функции в C++ и не объясните, что она делает, то скорее всего я вас не пойму **:(**..

Comment: А что вам, собственно, нужно? Просто что-то выучить ради того, чтобы выучить? Или реализовать какую-то конкретную задачу?

Comment: Ггг. Хэшкод в своем репертуаре: слишком спорно. По-моему, тут больше подходит "слишком очевидно" :)

Comment: @Flammable скорее ради любопытства

Comment: @ХэшКод как можно закрывать по причине "Слишком спорно", если все уверенны в одном ответе - Java?

Comment: @danpetruk уж не знаю, чем руководствовался человек, закрывавший вопрос с пометкой "слишком спорно", но это вопрос стоило бы закрыть хотя бы потому что он во-первых, слишком непрофессиональный, ламерский, если угодно (что-то наподобие "кто сильнее, кит или слон"), и тут вы явно сильно себе польстили, ссобщив, что ваша квалификация "в состоянии между новичком и среднечком",  во-вторых, обсуждался миллионы раз, и в-третьих, ответ на него легко находится с помощью гугла, что вы, видимо, сделать просто поленились

Comment: @DreamChild, тут добрая половина всех вопросов (как бы не больше) успешно гуглится.

Comment: @Flammable что крайне печально

Comment: Java-то учится проще, но вот реальное продолжение - вопрос - а на чем и какие задачи стоит программировать?

Comment: @DreamChild, а Вы, судя по этим комментариям боитесь, что достойный Вашего внимания вопрос затеряется среди тех, ответ на которые легко гуглится?

Comment: @avp, да, знаете ли, трепещу от одной только мысли о возможности  этого ужасного события

Comment: @avp, у меня очень небольшой опыт программирования на Java, но что меня по-настоящему напрягало, так это необходимость для каждого пука создавать класс. В результате писанины было немерено. 

У любого языка есть свои плюсы и минусы. Думаю, эту тему нужно закрыть.

Comment: @mikillskegg, вот с излишней писаниной на Java я абсолютно согласен.

Comment: >> вот с излишней писаниной на Java я абсолютно согласен.

В С++ этой лишней писанины (только другого рода) еще больше.

Comment: @Flammable, раскройте тему, плиз.

Comment: на самом деле, если посмотреть на количество вопросов по java и c++ можно увидеть что вопросов по java задают гораздо больше. (если посмотреть на тот же so). Выводы делайте сами.

Comment: @Viacheslav, выводы могут быть разные. Например, что в мире учебных курсов по Java больше, чем по C++.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Java. Почему?

- автоматическое управление памятью;
- отсутствие прямой работы с памятью;
- небольшое по сравнению с С++ количество неочевидных способов выстрелить себе в ногу;
- прекрасно документированный и интуитивно понятный фреймворк.

Answer (score 5):

Однозначно, Java проще.

Comment: Но почему?

Comment: Потому что автоматическое управление памятью - раз, отсутствие прямой работы с памятью - два, небольшое по сравнению с С++ неочевидных способов выстрелить себе в ногу - три, прекрасно документированный и функциональный фреймворк - четыре.

Comment: @Flammable лучше напишите это ответом, а не коментарием

Comment: В джаве нет таких  свойств С++, как указатели, множественное наследие, перегрузка операторов. Дженерики на порядок проще, чем шаблоны. Нет необходимости контролировать освобождение динамически выделенной памяти; это делает сборщик мусора. Это то, что на вскидку пришло в голову.

Comment: По своему опыту - Java проще. 

Опять же IMHO управление памятью (а также отсутствие указателей и т.п.) тут ни при чем. Мне даже наоборот, иногда этого не хватает.

Вот вся система работы с классами проще, очевидней и предсказуемей.

Comment: @mikillskegg Звучит прямо как приговор: Java проще, ну вы понимаете - типо для придурков, а вот С++ - да это для высоколобых :))

Comment: @Barmaley, не беспокойтесь. Python, на мой взгляд, еще проще. А я им пользуюсь по работе регулярно. В последнее время даже чаще, чем С++. Так что я глупее джавистов!

А вообще, не надо мне приписывать то, что я даже и близко не писал.

Comment: @mikillskegg мне то чего беспокоиться - я просто отметил общее впечатление от вашего ответа: он так воспринимается. Надо было еще отметить и мощность и скорость разработки и все такое - ну вы и сами знаете

Comment: @Barmaley, мне кажется, это Ваше оооочень субъективное впечатление.

Comment: @mikillskegg конечно субъективное впечатление - не спорю. Мне кажется простота должна уравновешиваться чем-то - чего я не увидел в вашем ответе.

Comment: @Barmaley, ну прямо как на экзамене. Причем, у очень занудного экзаменатора. Что ТС спросил, то я и ответил.

Comment: @mikillskegg и @Barmaley, Java явно не "для придурков". Язык упрощен лишь с той целью, чтобы разработчик мог сосредоточиться на основных векторах разработки, а не на возню с памятью и борьбу с указателями. Именно поэтому Jav`у любят, имхо =) И, в современном мире это становится мейнстримом среди разработчиков языков программирования...и это правильно. Скажите мне, если вы с этим не согласны, мол "Asm, хардкор.."

Comment: Прекратите уже склонять Java. Либо джаву, либо Java. Откуда такая мода пошла...

Comment: @Flammable кто посмел склонять Java? Я тут людей минусую уже только за одно то что пишут JAVA или Ява :)

Comment: @Barmaley,

>> Francesco:
>> Именно поэтому Jav`у любят, имхо

Comment: Как ее (джаву) не называй, а надо признать, что из языка для программирования пылесосов получилась хорошая вещь. 

Интересно, связано ли это с тем, что по крайней мере трое разработчиков  писали текстовые редакторы (vi, emacs, jove)?